# Too few arguments in function call while trying to call function with the same name from another namespace

Tags: c++, visual-c++, namespaces

I'm getting a "too few arguments in function call" while trying to call a function from another namespace that happens to have the same name with the function it's being called from. Here, you can see what I mean:

```
namespace doa::texture {
   using namespace internal::texture;

      Texture* const CreateTexture(const std::string& name, const std::string& pathToTextureImage) {
         //below should call internal::texture::CreateTexture, not doa::texture::CreateTexture
         Texture* texture{ CreateTexture(pathToTextureImage) };
         ... //implementation detail
      }
}

namespace internal::texture {

   Texture* const CreateTexture(const std::string& pathToTextureImage) { ... }
}
```

I can easily fix the error by slapping an `internal::texture` in front of the function call but since I'm using the `using namespace internal::texture` directive, the compiler should be able to pick it up.

I can also move the `CreateTexture` function from the namespace `internal::texture` to `doa::texture`. But I would like to avoid that.

How can I fix this without moving the function or putting `internal::texture` in front of the call, and why this thing happens in the first place? This is simply a case of function overloading, why do namespaces cause such a thing to happen? Thank you.

[image]

P.S. The functions are defined in a separate file. like this:

```
//irrelevant implementation details are left out
namespace doa::texture {

   Texture* const CreateTexture(const std::string& name, const std::string& pathToTextureImage);
}

namespace internal::texture {

   Texture* const CreateTexture(const std::string& pathToTextureImage);
}
```

Comment: @ChrisMM Actually, it is, in a header file. Let me edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Your code is affected by name hiding.  Within `dao::texture::CreateTexture()`, when you use the name `CreateTexture`.  the full name `dao::texture::CreateTexture` hides things named `CreateTexture` from other namespaces.   The `using namespace internal::texture` does not change that.   This means, within `dao::texture::CreateTexture()` you still need to give the full name of `internal::texture::CreateTexture` to use it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @Peter. I slapped an `internal::texture` before calling the function because I didn't want to change its name. Other possible fixes include changing the name of the function or moving the function into `doa::texture`. All of them work. By the way, can you edit your comment to fix the `dao`s into `doa`s, Doğa is my real name I use it as a namespace name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to try to put a few pieces of the C++17 standard (draft) together, and hope I'm not misinterpretting it :)

From the unqualified name lookup:

> 1 In all the cases listed in 6.4.1, the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories; name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name. If no declaration is found, the program is ill-formed.
>
> 2 The declarations from the namespace nominated by a using-directive become visible in a namespace enclosing the using-directive; see 10.3.4. For the purpose of the unqualiﬁed name lookup rules described in 6.4.1, the declarations from the namespace nominated by the using-directive are considered members of that enclosing namespace.

From using directive

> 2 A using-directive speciﬁes that the names in the nominated namespace can be used in the scope in which the using-directive appears after the using-directive. During unqualiﬁed name lookup (6.4.1), the names appear as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the using-directive and the nominated namespace. [Note: In this context, “contains” means “contains directly or indirectly”. —end note]

From Name Hiding

> 1 A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a nested declarative region or derived class (13.2).

Specifically, with this last part, I believe it means that the `CreateTexture` function in `doa::texture` hides the `CreateTexture` in `internal::texture` even though it is within a different namespace. Basically, the compiler sees `CreateTexture` in the `doa::texture` namespace, then stops looking, and hence ignored the one from `internal::texture`

Comment: "During unqualiﬁed name lookup (6.4.1), the names appear as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace" I believe this means, using the `using` directive is the same thing as moving the function all together to the `doa::texture` namespace. If that is the case, all should work well, because in that case the program actually compiles and works, `doa::texture::CreateTexture` doesn't hide `internal::texture::CreateTexture`. Now I'm even more confused :D.

Comment: I think the part from `Name Hiding` takes precedence and ends the lookup. And sorry, I fixed the typo -- I use a namespace called `dao` a lot

Comment: Hmm, in that case C++ doesn't care about the parameters a function takes while looking up a name declaration. I drew this conclusion because changing the order of declaration in the header file did nothing. I think the only way to fix this is by typing `internal::texture` in front of the function call. Thank you now I know the reason :) P.S. dao stands for data access object, or something else?

Comment: C++ cares about parameters, but as soon as something with the same name is declared in an enclosed scope, it takes precedence and hides those above. See a simplified example here: https://godbolt.org/z/b3Uz4s   DAO is data access object, for DB work.

Comment: I looked at the example you gave. Point taken, thank you for your time @ChrisMM :).

Comment: @DogaOruc I think the important bit not specifically addressed is the "which contains both the using-directive *and the nominated namespace*" part that you left out of the quote: `internal::texture::CreateTexture` will be seen from `doa::texture` as if it was declared at global scope. Therefore the `doa::texture::CreateTexture` (which is defined in a nested declarative region of the global one) will take hide it.