# C++ name resolution woes

Tags: c++, c++17

I am have a custom class that I want to provide a templated version of the `sin` function to - I've called it `foo` in my minimum verifiable reporduction. Due to some template meta programming elsewhere, it's advantageous for my `sin` function to have the same name as the normal `sin` function as it is doing the same job, just on different types.

However, the following will not compile:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

namespace test
{
    template <std::size_t size>
    class foo
    {

    };

    template <std::size_t size>
    void sin(const foo<size>& f)
    {
    }

    template <class T>
    void bar(const T& x)
    {
        using namespace ::std;

        sin(x);
    }
}

int main()
{
    test::bar(0.5);

    std::cout << "Done...";

    std::getchar();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
..\test\problem.cpp(23,3): error: no matching function for call to 'sin'
                sin(x);
                ^~~
..\test\problem.cpp(29,8): note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'test::bar<double>' requested here
        test::bar(0.5);
              ^
..\test\problem.cpp(14,7): note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'foo<size>' against 'const double'
        void sin(const foo<size>& f)
             ^
1 error generated.
```

I am surprised by this. Is there a way to get `bar` to compile without using template meta programming hacks to create several versions of `bar`?

Fails in Clang 9 and MSVC 2019.

Comment: What happens if you use `std::sin(0.5);`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Too few arguments in function call while trying to call function with the same name from another namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59121445/too-few-arguments-in-function-call-while-trying-to-call-function-with-the-same-n)

Comment: I forget exactly why, but use `using std::sin;` instead of `using namespace ::std;`.  First, it gets it to work, and secondly you don't want to import all of `std` just for one function.

Comment: @Fred Larson, I've updated the example to be clearer. I know I could use `std::sin`, but ultimately I `bar` may be passed a `double` or a `foo<>`.

Comment: You have a case of the "From Name Hiding" mentioned in the answer linked by @ChrisMM. Minimum necessary change: `::sin(x);`.

Comment: Incidentally, do you *really* want your `sin` function to be a `void`?

Comment: @NathanOliver- Reinstate Monica - perfect, you are a genius :-)

Comment: @Adrian Mole, your solution also works nicely - thank you!

Comment: @Adrian Mole, it's not returning void in the production code, this is just a mock up to get the compiler error - but thanks for mentioning :-)

Comment: @keith - Also, with that, you don't need the `using namespace ::std` - `sin` exists also in the global namespace.

Comment: @Adrian Mole, ah nice one - thank you so much for the pointers :-)

Comment: @keith `<cmath>` [is not guaranteed](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/requirements#headers-4) to introduce `sin` into the global namespace. It just will do so in practise because too much code depends on it. I have seen major implementations differ in practice on the question of whether just the original C standard library functions or also the C++ overloads are introduced into the global namespace. I would consider this a compatibility feature one best does not rely upon…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between a using directive and a using declaration. `using namespace ::std;` is a using directive. As far as unqualified name lookup is concerned, a using directive basically just forwards name lookup to also search namespace `::std` if a name was not found at the point name lookup reaches the nearest namespace that encloses both, the namespace that contained the directive and the namespace nominated by the directive [[namespace.udir]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udir#2). In your case, this means name lookup would have to reach the global namespace before it could find `::std::sin`. However, name lookup will reach the namespace `test` first, which contains a function named `sin`, and then just stop because it has found what it was looking for [[basic.lookup.unqual]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup#unqual-1). What you want is a using declaration:

```cpp
    template <class T>
    void bar(const T& x)
    {
        using std::sin;

        sin(x);
    }
```

Contrary to a using directive, a using declaration directly introduces the declared name into the scope in which the using declaration resides [[namespace.udecl]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#1), which means `std::sin` will be found right away. Now, this means normal unqualified name lookup will not find `test::sin` from within the block scope after the using declaration anymore. However, thanks to argument-dependent name lookup [[basic.lookup.argdep]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.argdep), `test::sin` will be found and part of the overload set again in case `T` is an instance of `test::foo`…

Comment: Note that using directives have more immediate effect for *qualified* lookup; it’s only for unqualified that it ”puts names in the nearest common containing namespace”.

Comment: @DavisHerring True, I modified that sentence to make clear that this only applies to unqualified name lookup…

Answer (score 2):

Here's a 'quick fix' based on (a) the comments and (b) the answer linked in the comments. A minimal version of your `bar` function would be:

```cpp
    void bar()
    {
        ::sin(0.5); // Without "::" your templated "test::sin" hides the global namespace
                    // version - which is here referenced EXPLICITLY.
    }
```

Comment: Feel free to suggest I delete this if it's considered "bad form" to post such a 'known duplicate' answer.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work with `test::bar(test::foo<5>());` whereas the answer by @Michael Kenzel does and is more idiomatic - but I've upvoted as it does work in the context of my simple example :-)